# Javascript : How to make a element clickable that was created in a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, null

Hey I have a problem that I don't know how to solved.
To make simple. I have a script that create element based on what I have get from a server.
At moment I create an image with the id "add"
And I want when we click on this image to trigger a function so I did a little script

```js
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
    alert('ADD !'); // <- For the test
}
```

But I get a problem when **Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null**. I thing this because I create this element in the other function and he is not directly in the html code. But I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: so, you can run the code that adds the handler after you insert the element in the DOM.

Comment: Show how you add the element..........

Answer (score 2):

You have to append the element to the document:

```
document.appendChild(yourElement);
```

Then you have to add an EventListener to your object:

```
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click", 
function() { 
alert('test'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your example is not long enought to answer you properly but to do want you want, you need to create your element, then attach your event to the element. I'm pretty sure you are trying to set the event on a element that doesn't already exist in DOM